# Android Studio adding a drawable resource to active tab in tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I am trying to add a white triangle to the bottom of tabhost to indicated the open tab like this: [image]

I have the white triangle png. Just wondering how I can style tabhost to add an image below the text for active tabs

This is the background resource I am setting to the tabhost.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tabselectedcolor"     android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tabunselcolor" />
</selector>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: not a complete solution, but you can try https://github.com/kpbird/TriangleTabs

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt, but have you looked into using the [setCompoundDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method of the TextViews inside your tabhost?

Something like this

```
textViewTitle.setCompundDrawables(null,null,null,triangleDrawable);
```

This might be worth looking into.. you could then add or remove the drawable when a tab is switched.